# Why are debit cards treated as a second-tier pay card (at best) whereas credit cards are first-tier?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card

I have a debit card, meaning I am 100% guaranteed to actually have the money or I can't use the card to pay for the transaction. It will refuse, even if it's just 1 cent over the amount I currently have in my bank account. It's boolean. Super strict. Either I have the money or not. Zero flexibility. Just as want it.

Meanwhile, a credit card will allow the consumer to buy things without actually having that money, with the assumption that he or she will pay it "at some later point", up to a certain limit of course.

It seems to me that a debit card, the kind I have and have always had, should make every money-accepting entity roll out the red carpet for me and stick a big cigarette in my mouth while telling me how good my hair looks and how slim I look today, and do I want a complementary drink to go?

Instead, it's the exact opposite: I'm harassed and treated worse than dirt, oftentimes downright **refused service entirely** for not having a credit card, even though a customer using such a card could be compared to a homeless person begging for change in the gutter.

It makes no sense to me. Why is this completely backwards from how it should logically be? Why do they *prefer* the uncertainty of never getting paid over being 100% guaranteed to get the money? What kind of insane Bizarro World have I ended up in?

Comment: Can you specify your location? And maybe give some more details to support your conclusion that debit card users are treated worse?

Comment: you might consider reading and editing your question, to lessen the emotion, and 'rant' aspect. I did not vote, but can understand why someone voted down. There is an excellent question to be had here.

Comment: Also - have you considered asking the specific merchants who are showing these behaviors why?

Comment: If your debit card has no Visa/Mastercard logo on it, it's probably a pain to process.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily the case.  For instance, the grocery store I usually shop at accepts debit cards, but not credit cards.  I think (though I'm not positive) many gas stations charge a few cents more for a credit card purchase, while debit cards get the cash price.

Comment: My debit card has a much higher credit limit than my credit card.

Answer (score 7):

It’s precisely because a charge on a debit card won’t go through if you don’t have the money. If you trash your hotel room or crash your rental car, charging the repair cost to a credit card is more likely to succeed than charging it to a debit card.

Remember, it’s the credit card company that takes the risk of you not paying, and not the retailer. The retailer gets paid immediately by the card company, and doesn’t have to pay it back if you then fail to pay your credit card bill.

Comment: Also, a credit card allows the customer to spend money they might not actually have at the moment.  Since the vendor will get paid regardless of when (or even if) the customer pays their credit card bill, this is a win for the vendor.

Comment: If I use my debit card at the grocery store, it asks me if it's debit or credit, and the charge goes through if I choose credit. Can hotels or rental companies charge a debit card as a credit card? Or is something else happening when I make that choice at the grocery store?

Comment: Don't many hotels already put a hold on your card ahead of time to ensure damages are paid for?

Comment: @milk that could be a separate question.

Comment: @IVcrush They normally only hold enough to cover your likely food and beverage spend, not the cost of renovating a trashed room and replacing the bed, TV and bathtub.

Answer (score 2):

If you buy a pack of gum with your credit card, the corner store gets your money immediately, the same as if you had paid with a debit card. If you fail to pay your credit card, it is the *bank which issues your credit card* which loses money. They are the ones who assess whether you will be able to use your card and repay it; the corner store has no ability to guess whether you will repay them.

As to why you might be refused service for a debit card - the store with the card terminal needs to decide *in advance* which cards it will accept. They pay a monthly fee to stay on the network of that provider type, and they pay a percentage of the transaction value for every transaction that occurs. For simplicity and to avoid some of these fixed costs, many small stores only get a couple of methods of payment. Though typically CC fees are higher than debit fees, so in my area at least, it is more common for a store to accept debit instead of credit, compared to your hypothetical scenario.

Comment: @dwizum Fair comment; correcting now.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are thinking about the fact that you have a debit card means that, if your transaction is approved, you are guaranteed to have the money available to pay. However, what you are failing to understand is that, from the merchant’s perspective, this is true whether or not you use a debit or credit card, because if you have a credit card, then the bank is ultimately paying the merchant, not you, and the bank has more money than you do.

Let’s say that you try to buy something where it is not known when you start how much the final total will be (perhaps a gas station, rental car, or hotel).  They will guess at a total and ask the bank if the transaction is approved. If the final bill is higher than they anticipated, it usually isn’t a problem for a credit card, because the bank has lots of money, and the merchant doesn’t care if you are spending more than you can pay or not. If it is a debit card, however, the merchant might not get paid if the customer is short on funds.